# python convert unicode code value to string, without '\u'

Tags: python

In the below code,

```
text = "\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8"
```

Is there a way to convert the unicode code above to keeping the value only, and remove "\u" from it.
So `"\u54c8"` becomes `"54c8"` instead.

In javascript I can do `text.charCodeAt(n).toString(16)` , but I can't figure out the equivalent solution in python.

I tried to use regex to match it,

```
pattern = re.compile('[\u0000-\uFFFF]')

matches = pattern.finditer(text)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

But all it did was printing out the character that the unicode value represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular list comprehension to map over the 4 characters in `text`, and use `ord` to get the `ord`inal (integer) of the codepoint, then `hex()` to convert it to hexadecimal. The `[2:]` slice is required to get rid of the `0x` Python would otherwise add.

```
>>> text = "\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8"
>>> text
'哈哈哈哈'
>>> [hex(ord(c))[2:] for c in text]
['54c8', '54c8', '54c8', '54c8']
>>>
```

You can then use e.g. `"".join()` if you need a single string.

(Another way to write the comprehension would be to use an f-string and the `x` hex format:

```
>>> [f'{ord(c):x}' for c in text]
['54c8', '54c8', '54c8', '54c8']
```

)

If you *actually* have a string `\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8`, i.e. "backslash, u, five, four, c, eight" repeated 4 times, you'll need to first decode the backslash escape sequences to get the 4-codepoint string:

```
>>> text = r"\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8"
>>> codecs.decode(text, "unicode_escape")
'哈哈哈哈'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:
You can ignore non-ASCII chars and encode to ASCII, or you can encode to UTF-8

```
text = "\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8\u54c8"
utf8string = text.encode("utf-8")
asciistring1 = text.encode("ascii", 'ignore')
asciistring2 = text.encode("ascii", 'replace')
```

You can refer to https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch03s18.html